# Resize UITableView height, and keep scrolled at bottom

Tags: ios

Im trying to resize the tableview's height with a animation, it works fine by animating the tableview's frame.size.height.

The problem is, i have a tableview that is 200px height and scrolled to the bottom, i want to animate this to 100px, i run a simple

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.245f animations:^{
 CGRect frame = tableview.frame;
 frame.size.height = 100.f;
 tableview.frame = frame;
}];
```

this works fine, but after i resized it it is no longer scrolled to the bottom of the tableview. i want the tableview to always be scrolled at the bottom while animating. i tried  alot of differnet things like calling

```
[tablview scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

right before/after i start the resize animation, but i have not managed to get them to sync 100%. Is there a way to resize the tableview while the bottom of the tableview displays the last element of the scrollview.

Comment: Use [UIView animateWithDuration:animations:completion:] instead?

Comment: I want the scrollanimation to occurs with the resize animation not after, but thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem, there might very well be a better solution but this actually works quite well :)

Before i start animating i see if the contentSize.height is larger than the target height, if so i do following:

```
if (mMessages.contentSize.height > 150.f)
{
    CGFloat expandedOffsetY = 52.f;
    CGFloat collapsedBottomOffset = (150.f + 18.f);
    CGFloat expandedBottomOffset = (MIN(320.f, mMessages.contentSize.height) + expandedOffsetY);
    tableFrame.origin.y = (collapsedBottomOffset - expandedBottomOffset) + expandedOffsetY;
}
else
{   
    tableFrame.origin.y = 18.f;
    tableFrame.size.height = 150.f;
}
```

this will put the tableview in a minus origin.y, then i have wrapped the tableview inside a "parent" uiview with clip sub views = YES.

Then i have a "completed" animation block that "resets" to the target values.

```
CGRect tableFrame = mMessages.frame;
tableFrame.origin.y = 18.f;
tableFrame.size.height = 150.f;
mMessages.frame = tableFrame;

if (mMessages.contentSize.height > tableFrame.size.height)
{
    float contentOffsetY = mMessages.contentSize.height - tableFrame.size.height;
    mMessages.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0f, contentOffsetY);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the contentOffset of the table view as you animate the frame.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.245f animations:^{
 CGRect frame = tableview.frame;
 frame.size.height = 100.f;
 tableview.frame = frame;

 float contentOffsetY = tableview.contentSize - tableview.frame.size.height;
 tableview.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, contentOffsetY);

}];
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, im afraid it does not look like i want it to, after doing a little digging it looks like setting the contentOffsetY while animating the height gives some weird behavior (sorry but abit hard to explain). But the result is not that the bottom of the tableview animates upwards while resizing.

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.245f  animations:^{
         CGRect frame = tableview.frame;
         frame.size.height = 100.f;
         tableview.frame = frame;
 }  completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        // Find your last indexpath
        [tablview scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
 } ];
```

Comment: I want the scrollanimation to occurs with the resize animation not after, but thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling the tableview to the bottom in the animation block was working for me, with one little twist: when I reduced the hight of the tableView I called scrollToIndexPath without animating, and when I expand the tableView I called the scrollToIndexPath with animation.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) { [weak self] in
    guard let strongSelf = self
        else { return }
    // ...
    // updateConstraints
    // ...
    strongSelf.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    if reduceSize {
        tableView.scrollToLastRow(animated: false)
    } else {
        tableView.scrollToLastRow(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Extension for UITableView

```
extension UITableView {

    func scrollToLastRow(animated: Bool) {
        let lastSection = numberOfSections-1
        let lastRow = numberOfRows(inSection: lastSection)-1
        let lastIndexPath = IndexPath(row: lastRow, section: lastSection)
        scrollToRow(at: lastIndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: animated)
    }
}
```